# Mocha with Mongoose, async, await

Tags: mongoose, async-await, mocha.js

I'm using mocha for my tests, when using async/await with it i get

```
  Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

my code

```
describe('ClientsMerge', () => {

    it('it should get all clients', async () => {
let clients = await Client.find();
console.log(clients);
    });

});
```

Comment: Please provide more information. And also make sure that you actually have an open connection for Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is to increase the timeout of your mocha tests

For example:

`mocha src/**/*.test.js --timeout 15000`